# Importing TypeScript Module located in path lower than current path throws Scope Error

Tags: module, scope, typescript, amd

In an attempt to put together an AMD-friendly TypeScript application skeleton, I've run into a snag:  I can't seem to drop down from my current path to import a module in another directory.  I can import modules that are above, but below throws an error:

`TypeScript Error: The name ''../core/View'' does not exist in the current scope`

Here the is the structure of my (very basic) app:

```
app/
 - core/
    - View.ts
 - views/
    - HomeView.ts
 - Application.ts
```

In my `Application.ts` file, I can successfully import a module like so:

```
import HomeView = module( 'views/HomeView' );

export class Application {
    constructor() {
        console.log( 'initializing Application' );
    }
}
```

Which, when using the --module AMD flag, correctly outputs

```
define(["require", "exports", 'views/HomeView'], function(require, exports, __HomeView__) {
    var HomeView = __HomeView__;

    var Application = (function () {
        function Application() {
            console.log('initializing Application', HomeView);
        }
        return Application;
    })();
    exports.Application = Application;    
})
```

Now, the problem is when I jump into `views/HomeView.js` and attempt to import my `core/View` BaseClass to extend from:

```
import View = module('../core/View');

export class HomeView {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Hello HomeView!');
    }
}
```

Which throws this complete error:

```
TypeScript Error: The name ''../core/View'' does not exist in the current scope
File: test/src/app/views/HomeView.ts
Start: 21, Length: 14

Line: import View = module('../core/View');
---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--
```

Is this a bug in the compiler, or is my understanding of module imports faulty?  Why would i be able to import `views/HomeView`, but not `../core/View`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get this to work using a root path - although I can't tell you why your relative path doesn't work.

```
import view = module("./app/core/View");
```

Comment: I've used almost the same fix. Paths are always relative to the root class (that is, the class which loaded the first module), so View.ts can always be accessed via `module("core/View")`

Comment: Wow --- sometimes you miss the most obvious things :)